# Methods how groups are related to geometries?

Tags: differential-geometry

Can anyone tell me about the groups those are related to 4-D geometry? I have find the references for 2-D and 3-D Euclidean Geometry.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are several groups related to 4d geometry, but first you have to specify first what 4d geometry you are interested in. I assume that it is the geometry of the Euclidean 4-space ${\mathbb E}^4$ (it also could be hyperbolic 4-space or Minkowski 4-space, etc.). Then the most important group to consider is the full group of isometries $\operatorname{Isom}({\mathbb E}^4)$ of ${\mathbb E}^4$. Algebraically, this group is the semidirect product
$$
{\mathbb R}^4 \rtimes O(4)
$$
where $O(4)$ is the group of orthogonal (linear) transformations of ${\mathbb R}^4$. Various (closed) subgroups of $\operatorname{Isom}({\mathbb E}^4)$ are also important, for instance, 4-dimensional crystallographic groups, which are discrete subgroups $\Gamma$ of $\operatorname{Isom}({\mathbb E}^4)$ such that the quotient ${\mathbb E}^4/\Gamma$ is compact. These groups are 4-dimensional analogues of the wallpaper groups. Another important subgroup comes from realization that ${\mathbb R}^4$ can be identified with the complex 2-space ${\mathbb C}^2$. This leads to the subgroup 
$$
{\mathbb C}^2 \rtimes U(2) < \operatorname{Isom}({\mathbb E}^4)
$$ 
consisting of isometric transformations preserving the complex structure.